# Does const-correctness matter with short inline functions?

Tags: c++, inline, const-correctness

I have written two short tests and compiled both with "g++ -S" (gcc version 4.7 on Arch Linux):

test1.cpp

```c
inline int func(int a, int b) {
    return a+b;
}

int main() {
    int c = func(5,5);
    return 0;
}
```

test2.cpp

```c
inline int func(const int& a, const int& b) {
    return a+b;
}

int main() {
    int c = func(5,5);
    return 0;
}
```

diff test1.s test2.s

```
1,5c1,5
<   .file   "test1.cpp"
<   .section    .text._Z4funcii,"axG",@progbits,_Z4funcii,comdat
<   .weak   _Z4funcii
<   .type   _Z4funcii, @function
< _Z4funcii:
---
>   .file   "test2.cpp"
>   .section    .text._Z4funcRKiS0_,"axG",@progbits,_Z4funcRKiS0_,comdat
>   .weak   _Z4funcRKiS0_
>   .type   _Z4funcRKiS0_, @function
> _Z4funcRKiS0_:
12a13,14
>   movl    8(%ebp), %eax
>   movl    (%eax), %edx
14c16
<   movl    8(%ebp), %edx
---
>   movl    (%eax), %eax
22c24
<   .size   _Z4funcii, .-_Z4funcii
---
>   .size   _Z4funcRKiS0_, .-_Z4funcRKiS0_
36,38c38,44
<   movl    $5, 4(%esp)
<   movl    $5, (%esp)
<   call    _Z4funcii
---
>   movl    $5, 20(%esp)
>   movl    $5, 24(%esp)
>   leal    20(%esp), %eax
>   movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
>   leal    24(%esp), %eax
>   movl    %eax, (%esp)
>   call    _Z4funcRKiS0_
```

However, I don't really know how to interpret the results. All I see is that test2 apparently generates longer code, but I can't really tell what the differences are.

A follow-up question: Does it matter with member functions?

Comment: If you are asking if the two programs are functionally equivalent -- yes. If you are asking which program produces optimal (shorter, faster, better, whatever) code -- compile them both with `-O4` before you compare. I expect you'll find they produce identical assembly.

Comment: Indeed... the generated code is identical with -O4... I feel stupid now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

const correctness is for humans, not for code generation

it makes it easier for humans to understand code, by introducing constraints on what can change

so, yes it matters for short functions also, since they can be called from code that is not as short and easy to comprehend in full at a glance

that said, your example functions do not illustrate const correctness

so, while this answers the literal question, probably you have misunderstood what const correctness is about, and meant to ask some *other question*, which i will refrain from guessing at

Answer (score 4):

Those functions aren't equivalent, one takes argument by value and the other by reference. Note that if you drop the references `&` then you are left with exactly the same functions, except that one enforces that you don't change the value of the copied arguments while the other doesn't.

Comment: But if they are inlined and don't change the value anyway, shouldn't the compiler optimize them into the same instructions? Logically they do the same thing.

Comment: What an optimizer should do is rarely as interesting as what an optimizer actually does.

Comment: @Asmageddon: I'm sure they will generate the same code if you compile with optimizations on.

Comment: Keep in mind the `inline` keyword is a compiler hint. The compiler will do whatever it pleases at the end of the day which is a good thing.

Comment: So, when writing inline functions like this, should I make them const-correct or leave them alone hoping compiler will optimize them?

Comment: I would pass by const reference in any case, because it is the correct thing to do. Pass by value _may_ give the same optimized code, or it _may not_, but technically you are asking for a useless copy to be made. Passing by const reference treats the function local variables simply as aliases, and in my experience it's never slower, but sometimes faster than pass-by-value or pointer (especially simple functions with not-so simple objects that have non-trivial constructors and destructors, pass by value may be _much_ slower).

Comment: That's up to you. const-correctness is generally a good thing but in this case I would say passing a couple `int` by value is trivial. Everyone has their own guidelines they follow.

Comment: @K-ballo: Re *I'm sure they will generate the same code if you compile with optimizations on.* If the compiler is smart enough, both will compile to the equivalent of `int main() { return 0; }`